# Number of Threads created by using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have used TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning to create a task for a background process which reads request off a concurrent queue and performs different actions.

```
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(x => PerformAction(), CancellationTokenObject, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

My understanding is that this might create a separate Thread to call "PerformAction()" but when I profiled this it shows that 
"System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart" method is being called many times.

Is this creating a new thread every time "System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart" is called. In that case it will be really odd that more than one thread is created for TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.

Answer (score 1):

First note that what exactly `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` does is not documented, so you shouldn't rely on it. What [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) says is (emphasis mine):

> It also provides a *hint* to the *task scheduler* that an additional thread *might* be required for the task

Now, according to [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,55), what the default `TaskScheduler` does for `LongRunning` is to simply start a single new background `Thread`.

Where does `ThreadHelper.ThreadStart` come in? That's part of an implementation of `Thread`, and is called once when the thread is starting. It seems that [its purpose is to make sure `ExecutionContext` is flowed](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,82).

So, I don't know how did you arrive at the conclusion that `TaskFactory.StartNew` with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` calls `ThreadHelper.ThreadStart` many times, but it shouldn't, at least not with the default `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: You are right about everything except that ThreadHelper.ThreadStart shouldn't be called many times. I think it is a helper method which doesn't create a thread but as you mentioned, it is used for ExecutionContext flow and I don't think calling it many times is a problem. It is just an internal implementation detail which we should worry about.http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,3deeb67a9c82bbf6
I have ThreadExecution logs from NewRelic which clearly show that this method is called everytime the long running task is executed.

Comment: @tangokhi "this method is called everytime the long running task is executed" Isn't that exactly what I said? What you said made me think you believed the method is called many times even when you create a single `Task`.

Comment: As I understood from your post, you mentioned that ThreadHelper.ThreadStart shouldn't be called each time a long running task is executed. but What I have observed is that for a long running task "a single background thread is created" but that background thread calls ThreadHelper.ThreadStart method everytime it executes. As I mentioned earlier, I inferred that by looking at the thread profiler logs from new relic and I also tried to get an idea by reading the code. Do you think I have misunderstood this?

Comment: On a separate note, I read some where that Long Running task shouldn't be created as even if we don't pass LongRunning flag, Tpl will look at the usage pattern and if it thinks the task should be long running it will create a separate thread.

Comment: @tangokhi I think we just misunderstand each other and are both saying the same thing: every time you start a `LongRunning` `Task`, `ThreadStart` is called.

Comment: @tangokhi To a certain degree, yes. If you don't use `LongRunning` for long running tasks, the `ThreadPool` will after a time figure this out and will slowly start creating new threads. But if you know for certain that a `Task` is long running, making it `LongRunning` won't hurt.